# Is Machine Learning+Neural Layers=Deep Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to the concept of machine learning .I am unclear about the difference between deep learning and machine learning.

Is the hypothesis, machine learning algorithm when combined with neural layers give a deep learning algorithm, correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Machine learning: One of the most common AI techniques, a self-adaptive algorithm that gets increasingly better analysis and patterns with experience or with newly added data.

Deep learning, a subset of machine learning, utilizes a hierarchical level of artificial neural networks to carry out the process of machine learning.

Comment: why is it better when there are more hidden layers?

Comment: Never say more layers is always better. Everything depends on the dataset and the problem we are trying to solve. Having more hidden layers will improve the representation of the problem as it can handle more complex functions. But it also increases the number of parameters of the model, thereby increasing the complexity. For some basic problems, it can lead to overfitting. Also, there are other issues to take care like vanishing gradients, degradation of training accuracy, etc. Always try to obtain the basic model which solves the problem. @yishairasowsky

Answer (score 1):

Deep learning is the subset of machine learning and machine learning is the subset of Artificial intelligence so most likely AI is a superset of Deep learning.

Deep learning is a type of learning focussing with Neural networks for the use cases object detection, classifications. 
object detections can be done only using deep neural network because there is a lot of parameters are to be learned.
for more check out kaggle.com , one of the best websites to learn and grow.

Answer (score 1):

### Machine learning:

Machine learning is the science of making computers learn and act like humans by feeding data and information without being explicitly programmed.

### Example:

When we come to the computer, We write a piece of code or program and tell the computer what to do step by step. But in ML we don't do that, the system learns on its own. We just provide the past data(called labelled data) and the system learns during the process what is known as training process, we tell the system if the outcome is right or wrong, that feedback is taken by system and it corrects itself and that's how it learns, it gives the correct output in most of the cases. Obviously it is not 100% correct but aim is to get as  accurate as possible.

### Deep Learning :

Deep learning is the sub field of ML which learns from the data by its own method of computing like our human brain. It make use of neural networks.